# How do I specify field masks for a field of a Repeated Field?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

Let's say you have a proto defined as the following:

```
message Zoo {
    repeated Cat cats = 1;
}
```

Let's say cat looks like this:

```
message Cat {
    google.protobuf.StringValue name = 1
    Decimal age = 2;
}
```

If I want to reduce the amount of data in Zoo such that sample data only contains `Cat` with only the name field, how do I do that?

Example:
A sample Zoo object will look like this:

```
{
    Cat: [{
        name = "sam";
    },
    {
        name = "hester";
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to do this with one field mask:

```
FieldMask zoo_mask = FieldMask.newBuilder()
    .addPaths("cats")
    .build();

Zoo getMaskedZoo(FieldMask mask, Zoo zoo) {
    Zoo.Builder zooDest = Zoo.newBuilder();
    FieldMaskUtil.merge(zoo_mask, zoo, zooDest);
    return zooDest.build();
}
```

How do I make it so that only the name displays for each `Cat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked the [Java implementation](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/FieldMaskTree.java#L237) and it's not supported in Java since cats is a repeated field. It's also not supported in c-core.

Your best bet would be to use reflection to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

From the [FieldMask documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask):

> A repeated field is not allowed except at the last position of a field mask.